# C# get return list string from function

Tags: c#

I have a problem on returning list from the function, i have try on giving a variable to get return list from function i get the return as below:

> System.Collections.Generic.List`1[System.String]

**Below is the code i do:**

I want to get the return list, the string will split into length 64 from the function it will have two string in the list, the string will be extend the code below is just the example string i set.

**Main function:**

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
  string test="DD1234455667788999663234324324345434543542252E323431431414313414DD1234455667788999663234324324345434543542252E323431431414313414";
  var test = toHexString(datass);
}
```

**Return function:**

```
 public static string toHexString(byte[] hexArray)
    {
        string hexString = "";
        List<string> hexlist = new List<string>();

        foreach (byte b in hexArray)
        {
            hexString += string.Format("{0:X2}", b);

            if (hexString.Length > 0 && (hexString.Length % 64) == 0)
            {
                hexlist.Add(hexString);
                hexString = string.Empty;
            }

        }
        return  hexlist.ToString();
    }
```

Comment: Look at ausing a `StringBuilder` instead. It's much more closely suited to what you are trying to do.

Comment: @Loocid would you mind to show me your idea?

Comment: If you want List<string> to be returned, then change the return type of toHexString method to List<string>, then return hexList.ToList() instead of hexList.ToString()

Comment: Just instead of using a `List<string>` use a `StringBuilder`. That's all you need to do.

Comment: @sharath.g your idea solve my problem thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is, when you call `ToString()` on an object or a class that has no explicit override of `ToString()` it returns its type name`

```
return hexlist.ToString();
```

Since `hexlist` is a `List<T>` you are getting the obvious result of

```
System.Collections.Generic.List`1[System.String]
```

You can either use something like `string.Concat`, or `string.Join` to return your desired result. Eg

```
return string.Concat(hexlist);
// or
return string.Join("",hexlist);
```

---

Or if you want a lazy style *Linq* *Enumerable* solution. You could use an  extension method like this for returning chunks of enumerable for an array

```
// returns enumerable chunks of size, and ignores any partial result
public static IEnumerable<IEnumerable<T>> GetChunks<T>(this T[] source, int size)
{
   for (var i = 0; i < source.Length; i += size)
      yield return source.Skip(i).Take(size);
}
```

Then you could write method like this

```
public static string GetHex(byte[] bytes, int size)
   => string.Concat(bytes.GetChunks(size).Select(x => $"{x:X2}"));
```

**Usage**

```
string test = GetHex(datass,32);
```

The result of this method returns a hex string, combined from chucks of 32 bytes

Comment: Thank you for you share, i not use yeild before, does it the same result as ref?

Comment: `yield` just returns when its executed, there is no real magic. you can think of it just giving a bit at a time to however calls it. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/yield

Comment: it might sound weird will it possible in future yeild will become a very comment use to call function that embedded in visual studio?

Comment: @Victor yield is a very common technique, its advantage is its lazy, meaning it doesn't enumerate an entire collection to return results

Comment: @Micheal Randall i just try some of the example, if use it too often will be lazy, i will try to avoid using it, once again thank you for your sharing

Answer (score 0):

Change the method to list will solve the return problem

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
  string test="DD1234455667788999663234324324345434543542252E323431431414313414DD1234455667788999663234324324345434543542252E323431431414313414";
  var test = toHexString(datass);
}




public static List<string> toHexString(byte[] hexArray)
    {
        string hexString = "";
        List<string> hexlist = new List<string>();

        foreach (byte b in hexArray)
        {
            hexString += string.Format("{0:X2}", b);

            if (hexString.Length > 0 && (hexString.Length % 64) == 0)
            {
                hexlist.Add(hexString);
                hexString = string.Empty;
            }

        }
        return  hexlist.ToString();
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

First, inside your if loop, you have accessed `test.Add(hexString);` which is inaccessible as per this code, I believe what you're trying there is `hexlist.Add(hexString);`

Second, `hexlist.ToString()` will always return `System.Collections.Generic.List1[System.String]`  because ToString cannot convert the list to a string directly and it returns the type of the object.

You can use `foreach` or a `stringBuilder` or `string.Join()`

Comment: My mistake for test.Add(hexString) i have correct it thank you for your share